# Pinterest Style Responsive Dynamic Grid System with Pure JavaScript – colm.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have do some search on this and i go through some tutorial but i really cant able to understand how its work...this is the website: http://www.cssscript.com/pinterest-style-responsive-dynamic-grid-system-with-pure-javascript-colm-js/

i am understand how to include the script, i just don understand how to modify the content. For example if i wan to make it only 3 column, how to i make it? i wan to know how to edit the number of row and column base on what we want. Thanks. Or if you can just do an example : i wan put 7 photo in the web page which is this 7 photo will auto fill up the size of the div.

[image]

Comment: What about 8 games? :D

Comment: @cheehung please provide us your effort of code hence people can help